# C++ compose string in one line to give as parameter

Tags: c++, string

In my program I have a program that takes a std::string as parameter. When I call this function I want to give it a large (about 5) composition of strings. Is there a native toString() function that can spit out strings#? Can it be done on one line?

What I want:

```
std::string a = "sometext";
std::string b = "someothertext";
somefunction(ToString(a+b+"text"));
```

Comment: Check out #include <string> with operator +. Also Google next time before you post please.

Answer (score 3):

This works aswell:

```
std::string a = "sometext";
std::string b = "someothertext";
somefunction(a + b + "text");
```

Comment: It does. I was overthinking the problem. I thought this would not be possible in such a "low level" language as C++. Maybe it's time for a coffee break for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) already has a [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) that will concatenate strings.  If you have

```
void foo(std::string some_name) { code in here }
```

And you want to pass it a combination of a bunch of string you can just use

```
foo(some_string + another_string + "some text" + even_another_string);
```

If all of your strings that you want to pass a literal strings then you will either have to add the [custom string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to one of them or convert one to a string

```
foo("this is a string"s + "another string" + "some more text");
//or
foo(std::string("this is a string") + "another string" + "some more text");
```